# Is it possible to use bitmoji in a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, snapchat

I have only a simple question: Is it possible to use bitmoji in a flutter application? And if it's possible, how is it possible? Does anyone konw how it could work, because I don't find a solution in the internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This guy is building a plugin for this:
https://github.com/matwright/bitmoji_flutter_plugin
Star it and cheer him on, and perhaps contribute, and it might be finished soon :)

Comment: @SOS video did you get answer?

Comment: well there is some guidelines here but i don't really understand how to apply it https://github.com/Bitmoji/BitmojiForDevelopers/blob/main/docs/DIRECT_AUTH_FOR_DEVELOPERS.md